# How could PC-Lint ignore an expression or macro

Tags: c, xc8, pc-lint

I have got a xc8 program where I predefine the EEPROM:

```
__EEPROM_DATA (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

Know I like PC-Lint to ignore such an expression in all my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way would be adding following to a .lnt file

```
// activate _to_semi keyword
+rw(_to_semi)

// assign __EEPROM_DATA to "_to_semi" expression that means everything from 
// "__EEPROM_DATA" until the next ";" will be ignored by PC-Lint             
-d__EEPROM_DATA=_to_semi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a MACRO defined by your
LINT program that will allow some conditional compilation.
Using SPLINT for instance, you could make it ignore __EEPROM calls
by using

```
 /*
  * definitions to ease splint checking in non xc8 compiler.
  */
#ifndef S_SPLINT_S
  __EEPROM_DATA (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
  __EEPROM_DATA (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
  __EEPROM_DATA (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
#endif
```

That way you can use all the checking of split without getting warnings about
the xc8/PIC specific code.

http://www.splint.org/manual/html/sec14.html